# Trying to select an item from a listView that is populated from an xml string array

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

So originally I had a string array in my mainactivity.java that populated a listview and I was able to click on an item in the listView and it would open up a new activity. I've now replaced that string array with an xml string array resource to populate the listView. But now I cannot select items from the listView. I hope I explained that well. Thank you for any help!

```
package com.example.zach.listview;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import  android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//public static String[] routes = {"Information","Crag Map","Main Wall","1.   Shark Bait - 5.9", "2. Rain Check - 5.8", "3. Rain Check Direct - 5.7+",
        //"4. Arocknophobia - 5.7", "5. Balls Deep - 5.9+", "6. Jingle Bells - 5.9", "7. Itching to Climb - 5.8-", "8. Hog Nose 5.10+",
        //"9. Slab Dance - 5.10", "10. Don't Screw with My Disco - 5.11c"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    //ListAdapter routeAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, routes);

        //Adapter with refernce to xml string array resourcde
    ListAdapter routeAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,     getResources().getStringArray(R.array.routeList));
    final ListView routeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.routeListView);
    routeListView.setAdapter(routeAdapter);



    routeListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,     int position, long id) {

                    // working way for selecting certain listview row from     above commented out string array
                    //String route =     String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

                    //attempt
                    String route =     String.valueOf(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.routeList)[position]);

                    if (route == "1. Shark Bait - 5.9") {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),     RouteDetails.class);
                        intent.putExtra("route", "Shark Bait");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    if (route == "Information") {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), RouteDetails.class);
                        intent.putExtra("route", "Birdsboro Rock Climbing     Quarry");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

            }
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to extract the array as a `final String[]` that you can access within the listener.

You also need to `equals` to compare strings.

```
final String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.routeList);
ListAdapter routeAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, values);

final ListView routeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.routeListView);
routeListView.setAdapter(routeAdapter);

routeListView.setOnItemClickListener(
        new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,     int position, long id) {

                String route = values[position];
                if (route.equals("1. Shark Bait - 5.9")) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,     RouteDetails.class);
                    intent.putExtra("route", "Shark Bait");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```